# C++ exceptions slow down 3dsmax when under visual studio debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2019, 3dsmax

I'm trying to debug a C++ 3dsmax plugin using Visual Studio 2019 and whenever I'm attached things run about 1000 times slower- an operation that would take 10 seconds has already taken about an hour. This seems to be due to a wall of thrown exceptions constantly spamming the output like this:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB97AB9709 in 3dsmax.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.

Unfortunately, this exception is in 3dsmax code, not my code, and so I'm unable to fix it. It doesn't seem to crash the software or cause any problems, it just slows down plugin debugging terribly when I attach. 3dsmax is already finicky when I try to attach, so attaching later in this process is not really an option.

I've read a few other similar questions, but none have offered solutions. These are C++ exceptions, so comments about Just My Code, etc. don't help as this is unmanaged. I've tried hiding the exceptions from the output window but it makes no difference. And the only exception settings I've managed to find are whether or not to break when encountering an exception (which I don't)- I have found nothing that just says to completely ignore exceptions and not slow down when encountering one.

Has anyone encountered anything that helps Visual Studio not slow down when encountering C++ exceptions?

Comment: I would also look into if there's something you could do to make 3dsmax throw fewer exceptions, but that would be sort of off topic here

Comment: 3ds Max does throw a lot of exceptions.  Have you tried using the correct version of Visual Studio for the build of Max you're targeting?  3ds Max 2021 is the latest public release, which uses Visual Studio 2017.  Also, ensure when you attach, the VS settings for "Attach To" are set to Native code only.  In my projects, the "Enable C++ Exceptions" compiler setting is set to `/EHa` ("Yes with SEH Exceptions").  Dunno if that will help.  I've never had my debugging sessions crippled by exceptions in the way you describe.

Comment: After trying the suggestions above (in particular, using the version of VS that 3ds Max is built against), one thing I would suggest is to verify that it's indeed 3ds Max and not a misconfiguration in your plugin (such as improperly implementing a `ClassDesc`, _etc_).  You can do this by simply removing your plugin and attaching to 3ds Max (after restarting, of course) and check that the flood of exceptions is still there.  Take that a step further by removing _all_ third party plugins, in case some other plugin is responsible.

Comment: @paddy, debugging using visual studio 2017 was the key. Didn't think to do that. I'm still getting exception spam but it's not slowing down the debugging session anymore. Thanks a bunch. Feel free to post this as the answer and I'll check it off.

Comment: Seems like removing 'managed' from the 'Attach To' was also necessary here.